# Abelian subalgebras of von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Is it true that one always have faithful normal conditional expectation from von Neumann algebra $M$ to any abelian subalgebra $A\subset M$? Does it hold for some special class of von Neumann algebras?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By a theorem of Takesaki (Section 6 in *Conditional Expectations in von Neumann Algebras*) there exists a normal conditional expectation onto every maximally abelian subalgebra of $M$ if and only if $M$ is finite. So finiteness of $M$ is necessary.

If $M$ is finite, there is a faithful normal conditional expectation onto every von Neumann subalgebra $N$. This can be constructed as the restriction of the orthogonal projection $L^2(M,\tau)\to L^2(N,\tau)$, where $\tau$ is a faithful normal tracial state on $M$.

Comment: what about $M$ is type III? Nothing can be said!!

Comment: If $M$ is type III, then there exists a maximal abelian subalgebra that is not the range of a normal conditional expectation. This seems like more than nothing to me.